# How to tune Wildfly to serve 20 requests per second?

Tags: performance, wildfly, undertow

I have developed a web application using JAX-RS (RESTeasy) and JPA (Hibernate) and deployed on Wildfly 10 (Linux machine, 4 CPUs, 8GB RAM). Where there are few users connected the application runs smoothly (requests served in less than a second), but when the traffic load grows it becomes unusable (30 seconds for a single request).

From the Wildfly console, I understand that the Undertow subsystem is receiving more or less 20 requests per second and using the application in Chrome I see the requests "pending" for more than 30 seconds.

How can I fine tune Wildfly to be able to serve more than 20 requests per second? Or, if it should already be able to do so, how can I find the bottleneck causing the hanging of requests?

Comment: run a profiler such as jprofiler or yourkit to see what is using CPU inside your application that is blocking your performance

Comment: Can you also provide your undertow configuration? What kind of work are you doing in your request handling?

Comment: Thank you @ctomc I ran JProfiler and caught some slow queries, fixing them requests are served much more smoothly. I'm running some more tests and I'll keep JProfiler active for some more time!

Comment: My specific issue was due not to WildFly but a leak in database transactions, which caused the app to hang. Not sure how to proceed, but I'd consider the question as invalid and candidate to be closed.